# Why is it necessary to implement IEnumerator when Implementing IEnumerable

Tags: c#, .net

Why is it necessary to implement `IEnumerator` when Implementing `IEnumerable`. Wherever I read its written only that it must happen but I just want the answer to the question of WHY.

Comment: Link/location where you've read that would be useful to clarify the question.

Answer (score 1):

The [`IEnumerable` interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable(v=vs.110).aspx) must implement a `GetEnumerator()` method, which returns an `IEnumerator`. In order to return an `IEnumerator`, there must be some implementation for you to return. Depending on your class, it may be possible to reuse an existing `IEnumerator` implementation, but it's also possible that your class has a custom way of being iterated over, in which case you'll need to create your own implementation of this interface.

There is a shortcut syntax available, however. You can use the `yield return` keyword in your `GetEnumerator()` method to let the C# compiler do the work of creating an IEnumerator implementation for you, based on some code that you provide inline. [This example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dscyy5s0.aspx#BKMK_CollectionClass) of a Collection class, for instance, implements it this way:

```
public class DaysOfTheWeek : IEnumerable
{
    private string[] days = { "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat" };

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < days.Length; index++)
        {
            // Yield each day of the week. 
            yield return days[index];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No; you can write an iterator.

Comment: If I have a collection as a field member then i dont need to implement IEnumerator but if I want my class object to be iterated then i must implement IEnumerator. Is that what you are trying to answer @StriplingWarrior.

Comment: @SumitRayakwar: If you want your class to be iterated, then there must exist an implementation of IEnumerator, but you don't necessarily have to implement it explicitly. You may be able to reuse some other class's IEnumerator (for example, the example in this answer could have just as easily been implemented by returning `days.GetEnumerator()`. Or, you may be able to use the C# Iterator feature to `yield return` your way out of creating a custom implementation.

Answer (score 0):

From MICROSOFT document, it says "When you implement IEnumerable, you must also implement IEnumerator."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerator?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: How does that answer the OPs 4 year old question - "I just want the answer to the question of WHY."? You're just repeating things already stated in the question.